# Typescript tsconfig to exclude some source files

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig, transpiler

I am trying to get Typescript to exclude certain files when compiling. However it doesn't seem to want to exclude them.

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "ref": "master",
  "path": "typings",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "target": "es5",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "build/src"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/global",
    "typings/index.d.ts",
    "./src/subClassA.ts"
  ],
  "files": [
    "./src/entry.ts"
  ]
}
```

It seems to be excluding the node_modules and typings. However the compiled code, still includes subClassA.

I would have expected the compiled code to not have any of the code from subClassA, however it does.

Comment: Are you using `subClassA` anywhere from your code?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

> Any files that are referenced by files included via the "files" or
>   "include" properties are also included. Similarly, if a file B.ts is
>   referenced by another file A.ts, then B.ts cannot be excluded unless
>   the referencing file A.ts is also specified in the "exclude" list.

If your `./src/entry.ts` file or any dependency of `./src/entry.ts` uses `./src/subClassA.ts` somewhere, then `./src/subClassA.ts` cannot be excluded unless `./src/entry.ts` is excluded too.

Related discussion: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7432

Comment: Thanks for the link, was a good read. Do you know of any work around for this?